# Rails : How can I get list of all area from city name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding, rails-geocoder

My Actual requirement is to get all Area names for a city. I wonder how can I achieve this.

I don;t want to maintain this list on my DataBase. I read articles on Geocode on google map but I can get only city name and area code from where my visitor is going to visit application.

Any Idea?

Comment: Have you find any solution of this question. i am on same problem

Comment: @Chiragthaker Not yet. Still looking for the solution. If you found anything please submit your answer here.